# How does angular watch changes in a model?

Tags: angularjs

How does angular watch changes in a model?

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', function (ProjectsRepository) {
    var pj = this;

    pj.PageIndex = 1;
    pj.PageSize = 50;

    var req = ProjectsRepository.Get(pj);

    faraAjaxConfig(req)
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.Success) {
                pj.Rows = result.Rows; // How detect changes in this and apply to ng-repeat
            }
            else {
                faraAjaxMessage(result.Messages, true);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: This video shows how to rewrite angular from scratch in 30 minutes, explaining how it works internally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk2WwSxK218

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the built in `$http`, which means you'll need to `$scope.$apply()` to kick off a digest cycle, which is where angular does its checking. In general, any data retrieved from an async source not using an angular service will need to notify angular of the changes this way. Websockets, ajax, web workers, etc.

(I'd recommend just using $http instead, cleaner all around)

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', function (ProjectsRepository, $scope) {
    var pj = this;

    pj.PageIndex = 1;
    pj.PageSize = 50;

    var req = ProjectsRepository.Get(pj);

    faraAjaxConfig(req)
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.Success) {
                pj.Rows = result.Rows; // How detect changes in this and apply to ng-repeat
            }
            else {
                faraAjaxMessage(result.Messages, true);
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
});
```

Comment: `ProjectsRepository.Get(pj);` uses `$http`

Comment: What's faraAjaxConfig? It seems to be coming out of nowhere.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh when a function call goes out of angular app you need to $scope.$apply() to kick off a digest cycle.

Comment: @DylanWatt `faraAjaxConfig` just add some funcs to req: `function faraAjaxConfig(promis) {
    promis.success(function () {
        // success
    }).error(function () {
        // error
    }).finally(function () {
        // finally
    });
    return promis;
}`